# Include directory in ng serve but exclude for ng build --prod

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm working with Angular 11 and with my normal workflow, what I'm looking to achieve is this:

- have mock JSON files in assets/data/testing
- run ng serve to watch and test code
- when satisfied, do ng build --prod to build dist/ but **not** include /testing/ folder in distribution

In angular.json under architect.build.options.assets I have

```
{
"glob": "**/*",
ignore": ["**/data/testing/**/*"],
input": "src/assets",
output": "/assets"
}
```

Works when I build but as takes the folder out when running ng serve!

What am I missing? Can this setup work?

---

Here's a basic copy of my angular.json file, leaving out most of the non-essential stuff.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "cpsa-web-angular": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/cpsa-web-angular",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "ignore": ["**/data/sample-files/**/*"],
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "/assets"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [...
            ],
            "scripts": [...
            ],
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [...
           ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [...
              ]
            },
            "staging": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.stage.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [...
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "port": 4200,
            "host": "0.0.0.0",
            "browserTarget": "cpsa-web-angular:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "cpsa-web-angular:build:production"
            },
            "staging": {
              "browserTarget": "cpsa-web-angular:build:staging"
            }
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [...
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "cpsa-web-angular"
}
```

Comment: It is in a test folder and that folder is under /assets. 
   I want to access it using HTTP requests.